# The difference between these modification

Tags: word-choice, modifiers

The sentence I saw in a book is below.

*The boy yelling is my brother.*

I suddenly wonder why *yelling* is modifying from behind *the sentence* .
I believe *The yelling boy is my brother.* is all right.

Please tell me the difference.

Comment: Please provide the context.

Comment: Sorry, there is no context. The book is grammar book. Does it depend on the context?

Comment: Yes, it is does. It always does. For example: "*Do you see the two boys there? The one yelling is my brother. The other one is my cousin.*" sounds perfectly natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand the sentence, it could be "The boy who is yelling is my brother". The attributive clause starting with WHO can be replaced by a present participle, yelling. That is why you see the sentence that you posted.

It seems to me "The yelling boy is my brother" will work too, but it doesn't sound as natural.